# Plotting individual line graphs for each region

Tags: r

Folks,

I have a dataset called dataforgraph. My three variables are Year, Income and regions. Year and Income are numeric and region is character.  In total I have 35 separate regions. I have plotted them all on one line graph but it is too messy and difficult to analyse. What I would like to do is plot each region on a separate line graph and show them all side by side 5 columns across 7 rows.

I'm new to R and I'm struggling with this. Any help would be most welcome.

(Year, Region, Income Ratio)
VALUES ('2010', 'Region A',5.1
'2011', 'Region A',5.1
'2012', 'Region A',5.6
'2010', 'Region B',5.2
'2011', 'Region B',4.8
2012, 'Region B',4.0)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16977010/2563804?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is without any data, code, clear desired output and attempts, and it's going to not get an useful answer but downvotes (not mine in this case) and maybe it's going to be closed, if you do not put them. Please try to add them to help us to help you.

Comment: This appears to create a scatter plot. I'm interested in a line plot (line graph)

Comment: Attempted to insert sample data but not too sure if I carried this out correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `par(mfrow=c(7,5))` before running the plots or `ggplot` solution mentioned by @hplieninger